# Admob Native ad is "stealing" an item

Tags: flutter, if-statement, dart

So after I've implemented the NativeAds, only 3 days after I've noticed that my *random* method of displaying the ad is stealing one item from the json.

So, currenlty I'm displaying the ads every *13 items*

```
if (index % 13 == 0)
            return adsContainer();
```

So this is *stealing* my *0* of json.

What could I do to stop this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about how it's *stealing* something? It's unclear what you're actually referring to - maybe some screenshots of expected and actual behavior might help?

Comment: Hi! So in my json I'm retrieving some items, and since it is starting in the index 0, the ads are going to be insert in that item, so it's now overriding the json item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found out, `0 mod 13 == 0`. In fact, [`0 mod` most all integers is `0`](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111330/how-do-i-explain-to-students-that-0-bmod-n-equals-0).

Why not just work around this by checking to make sure the index isn't `0` *before* checking if `index % 13 == 0`?

```
if (index != 0 && index % 13 == 0) // make sure ad container is only displayed when we're not on index 0 and on every thirteenth element thereafter
    return adsContainer();
```

Comment: Ups! You'r totally correct, thank you for the link with the explanation, that will help me alot  undestanding better this, but dart doesn't allow me to use _!==_, so 'm going with _!=_.

Comment: My apologies on the typo - I've edited to reflect this.